# Bash script help in getting the first digit from a number

Tags: shell-script, centos

How do I get the first digit from a number? For example, 25 - to get only the "2" from the 25.

This is what I tried:

```
echo -n "Enter age: "    
read age    
echo $(s:0:1)
```

Comment: What was your result?  What is `s` supposed to be in the third line?

Comment: it doesn't work. it display the entire "s:0:1"

Comment: It should be a parameter expansion `${s:0:1}`, not a command substitution `$(s:0:1)` (which should give you a command-not-found error, not the literal string `s:0:1`).

Comment: @DavidLloyd The script you posted wouldn't produce that output (it would report an error), you must have copied it wrong. Can you edit the question to show what you really executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX compatible solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "Enter age: "
read -r age
echo "$age"  
echo first digit: "$(echo "$age" | cut -c1)"
```

Example:

```
$ ./script.sh
Enter age: 25
25
first digit: 2
```

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: @DavidLloyd If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: A much slower solution than `"${age:0:1}"`.

Answer (score 22):

You're using the wrong variable `s` instead of `age` and parameter expansion works with curly braces `${...}`:

```
read -p "Enter age: " age
echo "${age:0:1}"
```

Comment: This should resolve the issues in the original script

Comment: As long as the number doesn't have a sign !

Answer (score 5):

The most basic and POSIX compatible way (assuming no sign) is:

```
echo "${age%"${age#?}"}"
```

In some shells (bash,ksh,zsh):

```
echo "${age:0:1}"
```

If the value could contain a sign, remove it first:

```
$ age=+23
$ age=${age#[+-]}
$ echo "${age%"${age#?}"}"
2
```

Comment: See also `printf '%s\n' "${age[1]}"` in zsh or yash (or `printf '%s\n' $age[1]` in zsh). Beware `echo -` outputs an empty line in zsh (as `-` is the end of option delimiter)

Comment: It may be possible to deal with a leading `-` by using `echo --` instead; many commands accept `--` as a delimiter to mean "what follows are positional arguments, not options"... but it will depend on what `echo` is being used. (Note that `echo` is often a shell built-in.)

Comment: No @Matthew there is no echo (builtin or external) that takes `--` as meaning "end of options", none. All will just output a `--`. Try it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (1) Both `${age[1]}` and `$age[1]` are **zshisms**, only work inside zsh and are not portable. Why use a "limited to one particular shell" syntax when a more portable solution also exist ?. (2) There is no issue with `echo -` as the `-` either doesn't exist (no sign) or, if it exists, it is removed with `age=${age#[+-]}`. Read the answer.

Comment: `${a[1]}` is zsh or yash like I said. Those are additional notes to complement your answer (which already mentions ksh93isms), it's not a critic to your answer. `echo ${a:0:1}` will output an empty line if `$a` is `-1`, it's still worth noting.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (1) I don't like to complement zshisms to my answer, thanks. (2) The use of `${age:0:1}` is correctly qualified as working in bash, ksh, zsh, I see no need for additional detail. (3) This answer clearly state: **(assuming no sign)**. And, if a sign exists, the way to remove it (portably) is also given. The sequence is  to do: `zsh -c 'age="-23";age=${age#[+-]};echo "${age:0:1}"'`, as explained in the answer, that works in most shells (even zsh). (4) The **only** shell that will print an empty line if a `-` is **not** removed is zsh (even in sh or ksh emulation). A **zshism**.

Comment: @Isaac, hmm, *partly* true, and in a fascinating way... both bash's builtin and GNU `echo` (from coreutils) *do* accept `--` to suppress interpreting further arguments as options. They *also* consider it as a positional argument, rather than ignoring it. That's actually fairly bizarre. That said, `--` works as expected with `printf` (both bash's builtin and coreutils).

Comment: @Matthew Both GNU /bin/echo and bash's echo do **not** accept options **after** arguments. So: `echo one -e "hell\no""` doesn't cut the `hello` with a newline because the option `-e` is not processed as such because it is **after** a normal argument of `one`. What you found is that a `--` (or `-`) is also treated as a valid argument and it invalidates following options. There are some (GNU) programs that accept options **after** arguments. A `head -n 1 file` will work in the same way as a `head file -n 1`, for example.

Comment: @Isaac, not just GNU. Also Python's argparse, I'm pretty sure git, and I would guess "better" parsers in general accept options anywhere. (And also accept '--' to mean 'no more options')

Answer (score 3):

As you mention `bash` in the title:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter a number: '
printf '%.1s\n' "$REPLY"
```

This *prints* only the first character of the string `$REPLY` (read by `read`).

To store this in another variable, `othervar`, use

```
printf -v othervar '%.1s' "$REPLY"
```

You could also just use a simple variable substitution, as mentioned by others,

```
printf '%s\n' "${REPLY:0:1}"
```

where `0` is the zero-based position in the string where we want to start pulling out data, and `1` is the length of the substring that we want.

You can assign `${REPLY:0:1}` to another variable directly:

```
othervar=${REPLY:0:1}
```